# Checkbox onclick change row color

Tags: checkbox, colors, background, onclick, row

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jemrfomy/

Once I click on a checkbox, it should change that particular tr's background color using the highlight class below:

```
.ui-table-highlight {
    background-color:#ffefbb;
}
```

I tried several solutions on stackoverflow but I think it perhaps is a problem in my css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its a problem with the hierarchy of your highlight CSS class it should be:

```
.ui-table tr.ui-table-highlight {
   background-color:#ffefbb;
}
```

As ".ui-table tr:nth-child" will override it otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Just add !important after the color in your css as

```
    .ui-table-highlight {
        background-color:#ffefbb !important;
    }
```

Updated your fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jemrfomy/1/

Best of luck for future :-)